# The navbar shakes when I scroll down using the animate function

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I face up to a weird issue when I scroll down clinking on an `<a>` link in the navbar, this one shakes or blinks. Here is my markup:

```js
(function($) {

    // Smooth scroll to the anchor
    $("nav a").on("click", function(event) {

        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.attr("href"),
            $section = $(id);

            event.preventDefault();
            $("html, body").stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $section.offset().top
            }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

          $("html, body").on("scroll wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
            $("html, body").stop()});
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4 {
    height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="jarallax" data-jarallax data-speed="0.03">
    <img class="jarallax-img" src="bg.jpeg" alt="">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section4">section4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="section1">
        test
    </div>
    <div id="section2"></div>
    <div id="section3"></div>
    <div id="section4"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jarallax@1/dist/jarallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Here are what I observed:

- When I click on a navbar link the script triggers and the page smoothly scrolls down however the navbar shakes up and down and blinks
- The bug appears only once then I need to refresh the page to observe it again
- This bug only works on Safari (I use the version 13.1)
- If I remove test in the section1 - it works most of the time and sometimes it blinks a bit
- Same behavior if I remove the font-family line in the css it only blinks
- If I remove transform: translate(-50%, -50%) in the css it works perfectly
- If I remove Jarallax it works as well (However I would like to keep it)

Jarallax library: https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax

I tried to recreate a condensed version of my bug, on my webpage the navbar shaking is amplified.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to put `nav` outside the `jarallax` div? I guess because it has a fixed position may cause problem.

Comment: still the same issue :/